# Spark data frame, JOIN two datasets and De-dup the records by a key and latest timestamp of a record

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I need some help in a efficient way to JOIN two datasets and De-dup the records by a key and latest timestamp of a record.

use case: Need to run a daily incremental refresh for each table and provide an a snapshot of the extract everyday
For each table get a daily incremental file: 150 Million records need to run a De-dup process against a history full volume file (3 billion). The dedup process need to run by a composite primary key and get latest record by the timestamp. every record contains key and a timestamp. Files are available in ORC and parquet format using spark.

Comment: Do you have any code you've started on that you can share as a starting point?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your help. I have a code which is functionally working  but it's not performing well with bigger datasets. I am looking for an approach to handle the joins/suffles efficiently.    grouped_rdd = df_final.rdd.groupBy(lambda tuple: (tuple[2], tuple[3], tuple[4], tuple[5])).mapValues(lambda v: list(v))       sorted_rdd = grouped_rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (k, sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))    
uniq_rec_rdd = sorted_rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (k, v[0]))        hist_rdd_paired = hist_df.rdd.map(lambda tuple: ((tuple[2], tuple[3], tuple[4], tuple[5]), tuple))

Comment: @SriBaru check `window` functions in spark. This can help you. Which version of spark are you using?

Comment: spark 1.6.1. Will try with window functions

Comment: @Iurii Nedostup, Looks like window functions are the right ones in our use case, dense_tank(). Also we are using a full outer join. rdd_joined = hist_rdd_paired.fullOuterJoin(uniq_rec_rdd). is there any better approach in spark to join two bigger datasets

Comment: first you can get most recent rows from table(again, window functions can help you with that) and then simply do join without relying on timestamp field; or you can do join and apply window function in one query. Try to use dataframes instead of RDD as it is much more faster in pyspark. Also you can replace window functions with joining dataframe to itself.